# how to suspended the background processes?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu-11.04

Below is the script named **bck_grd.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
i=2
while [ $i -gt 0 ]
do
echo HURRAY
done
```

When this infinite while loop is executed in foreground, it keeps on echoing message HURRAY and this script can be suspended by ^Z (ctrl+z)

Now if the same script is ran in background (i.e. bash bck_grd.sh &)then also it keeps on echoing message HURRAY and here if i try to suspend this script using ^Z, it doesn't work.
and the terminal gets tied up in displaying HURRAY message.

My question here is how can i suspend the above script while running it in background

I am using Ubuntu-11.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bring it to the foreground and then press `^Z`:

```
./bck_grd.sh &
fg
# Now press ^Z
```

(note that you would type the `fg` command while the script is echoing the output - it's okay, as long as you remember to press enter ;))

Comment: thanks for the prompt response but the actual problem with me here is that once i run background process `./bck_grd.sh &` **the terminal gets tied up in displaying HURRAY message** (i had edited my question) and terminal doesn't allow me to enter `fg` command

Comment: @pawanvinayak it allows, only your typing is scrolled off. So, simple press `CTRL-C` (for sure), immediatelly after enter `fg ENTER` and press CTRL-Z.

Comment: It might look like the terminal is not allowing you to enter any command, because it keeps pringting the `HURRAY` over and over again. So any time you press a character, it will quickly get scrolled up because multiple `HURRAY`'s will get printed. But the shell will get what you type. So just try to enter `fg<ENTER>` and then you should be able to use `^Z` or `^C`.

Comment: @kamituel thanks for replying back, it worked and it was a great way to test-out the reflexes of my fingers...!!! :)